# Is it possible to aggregate efficiently by quartile in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

For example suppose I have 10,000 sorted documents that I want to `aggregate()` on. But I'd like to group them into quartiles: top 25%, 25% - 50%, 50% - 75%, bottom 25%. Is there a way to this in one pipeline versus having to do 4 separate pipelines for each quartile?

Something like:

```
aggregate()
- Transform into {quartile1: [list of docs], quartile2: [list of docs], ...}
- Run other pipeline commands
```

Or do I need to run 4 separate `aggregate()` pipelines?

Thanks!

Comment: The real question is how do you know your results fall in between the "top 25%" or whatever by even running separate queries? It seems to me that there is a lot more calculation required or that there is some indicator on the document data already for even that to be possible.

Comment: Suppose it is already sorted. Like the top 25% would be documents 1-2500

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what you are asking, "can the aggregation framework to this?", then the answer would be no it cannot. You can possibly do something like this with mapReduce on the other hand. But the real thing I would want to present would be the reliability of this and furthermore as to "what would be the point?".

The best way to voice the skepticism here is to fully explain things.

The Aggregation framework cannot do this sort of thing because it would have no concept of "where it was  currently" in the process of processing your 10,000 documents. To to this, you need some kind of "variable" that is incremented as each of your "sorted" items is processed.

You could use the approach to "tag" items based on the values you are "sorting" on. But the question remains as to "how would you know" where a particular value was ranked in the overall result set. So unless there is a clear way to do that then you cannot project such a field.

Only if you were prepared to use a "set range" that was not necessarily a "quarter division" of all of the results would you be able to do this using `.aggregate()`:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "grouping": {
            "$cond": [
                { "$lt": [ "$score", 25 ]  },
                3,
                { "$cond": [
                    { "$lt": [ "$score", 50 ] },
                    2,
                    { "$cond": [
                        { "$lt": [ "$score", 75 ] },
                        1,
                        0
                    ]}
                ]}
            ]
        },
        "score": 1,
        "otherField": 1
    }},
    { "$sort": { "grouping"  1, "score": -1 }
])
```

On the other hand `.mapReduce()` does have access to such a global variable. So can basically inspect a counter in order to see if it is in your expected grouping. In basic form:

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function() {
        counter++;
        if ( counter % ( total / 4 ) == 0 )
            grouping++;

        var id = this._id;
        delete this._id;

        emit({ "grouping": grouping, "_id": id },this);
    },
    function() {}, // no need for a reducer
    {
        "out": { "replace": "results" },
        "scope": { "counter": 0, "grouping": 0, "total": 10000 },
        "sort": { "score": -1 }
    }
)
```

It basically does what you want. But not in a really flexible way or a very reliable way. Mostly because in most real world situations there is no guarantee that there are 10,000 results always, and usually especially if running one query with conditions to get a count and another to "tag" the results into their grouping.

As such, and considering that there is no real "aggregation" happening here at all, then probably the best approach is to simply query the data an list it out:

```js
var cursor = db.collection.find({}).sort({ "score": -1 });
var total = cursor.count();

var counter = 0,
    grouping = 0;

cursor.forEach(function(doc) {
    counter++;
    if ( counter % ( total / 4 ) == 0 )
        grouping++;
    doc._id = { "grouping": grouping, "_id": doc._id };

    // Do something with "doc"
});
```

Not really elegant, but pointing out the basic technique.

Also to note that arrays `[]` as you suggest are not a really great idea. Even in the 10,000 document scenario, the resulting 2,500 elements arrays and essentially 10,000 items in a single document response, is probably going to "blow up" the 16MB BSON limit. At the very least it is not very manageable and is better treated with a cursor.

So you can either choose the server to "tag" these items or just "tag" them as they are read. At least in the latter case you have access to a "cursor" for the results

Answer (score 0):

i think one needs 4 pipelines along the lines of that found in [mongo docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/).

```
db.articles.aggregate( [
                        { $match : { score : { $gt : 70, $lte : 90 } } },
                        { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } }
                       ] );
```

but against all normal db rules consider double-dipping or entering data twice. once for the cardinal field and again for the quartile field. this method is fugly but permits quick reads; one can conduct a simple find on a indexed field plus do a single agg.

```
{name: cartman, score: 56, quartile: 3 }
{name: kenny, score: 36, quartile: 2 }
{name: kyle, score: 76, quartile: 4 }

db.scores.find( {"quartile" : 3 });

db.scores.aggregate( [
                        { $group: { _id: null, count: { $quartile: 1 } } }
                       ] );
```

Comment: Actually, if there was a strict range such as between `75 - 100` and so on, then it would be possible in a single pipeline. Just a conditional projection really. But the question asked for the "list" of documents and was fairly clear from comments that results 1-2500 after sorting was considered to be the top 25%

Comment: oops. theres that day job getting in the way